# ZF2 include JS file if condition

Tags: php, jquery, localization, zend-framework2, timeago

Stupid question here.
ZF2, how can i include JS file depending on HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE.
I mean: inside my module.config.php file it looks like:

```
...
),
'js' => array(
    '/build/min.js' => array(
        '/vendor/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js',
        '/vendor/jquery.timeago/jquery.timeago.js',
        '/vendor/jquery.timeago/jquery.timeago.ru.js',
        ...
    )
),
...
```

I want to include

> jquery.timeago.ru.js

only when `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] == 'ru_RU'` 
where should i write this check ?

Answer (score 0):

Well your module.config.php is basically a PHP file, so you can always create a variable with your base array, make a test on `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` and add `jquery.timeago.ru.js` if needed. 
Don't forget to return the variable after, though

---

EDIT

```
<?php
    $arrayConfModule = array(
        ...,
        'js' => array(
            '/build/min.js' => array(
                '/vendor/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js',
                '/vendor/jquery.timeago/jquery.timeago.js'
        ),
        ...
    );
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] == 'ru_RU') {
        $arrayConfModule['js']['/build/min.js'][] = '/vendor/jquery.timeago/jquery.timeago.ru.js';
    }
    return $arrayConfModule;
?>
```

Shouldn't something like that work ?

Comment: ```php($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] = "ru_RU") ? '/vendor/jquery.timeago/jquery.timeago.ru.js' : '',```
Yeah, i know. i tested this and it works well.. but isn't it messy ? Also I have to write some map function to include files automatically depending on locale..should i write it somewhere before main config array or is there a possibility to do it in the same line using something like: ```php , 
 function(){
   return '  generated file url here'
}
 , ```

Comment: You could make this way nicer by using a filter https://github.com/RWOverdijk/AssetManager/wiki/Filters#services ... I'm just assuming your using this module as the array config looks like you are